# Unix script getting users with UID bigger than 500

Tags: unix

I am trying to write UNIX script which takes all users and prints only these, who has UID bigger than 500.

I wrote this line

```
cut -d : -f 1-3 /etc/passwd
```

but now I have no idea how to finish it.

If you have an example please share it with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk -F: '{if ($3 >= 500) { print $1 ":" $3 } }' /etc/passwd
nobody:65534
falsetru:1000
```